# Input data every tick from an Excel file

Tags: excel, netlogo

I've an external file (.xls) with a forecast prices. I need to upload these data in a way that the model read for every tick the associated value, for example:

at tick 1 the value of the price of 2015, 
 at tick 2 the value of the price of 2016; 
 at tick 3 the value of the pice of 2017;

and so on...

I need to install the extensions for Netlogo or there is another way to achieve my purpose?

Tahnk you very much for your attention and for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to make the file easy to read, I recommend saving it from Excel as a CSV file. CSV is a very simple, easy to interpret format, and is one the "Common Formats" in the "Save as..." dialog. Next, if possible, try isolating the data in a single column without a header like so:

[image: excel single column]

If that's not possible, no big deal, but it will make your life easier.

Once you do that, you can use [`file-read`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#file-read) to read the values out of the file one at a time.
To read it, I'd actually recommend reading the whole thing into a list during setup. Here's how:

```
globals [ prices ]

to setup
  ca
  ...
  set prices []
  file-open "/path/to/UPLOAD.csv" ;; or user `user-file` to allow the user to select a file
  while [ not file-at-end? ] [
    set prices lput file-read prices
  ]
  file-close
  ...
end
```

This puts all the values in a list `prices` that you can then read from each tick. If you want to read one item per tick, then it's just `item ticks prices` to get the `ticks`th item from the list.

Comment: Thank you very much, but after I've opened the file with the command file-open, how can I use file read to associate the value a my variable?                                                              file-open "UPLOAD.csv"

Comment: Edited my answer to expand on how to do the reading itself. Let me know if anything needs clarification.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! With function item ticks prices it's perfect thank you very much!!